# Циклы в питон. Почему цикл остановился

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
while a>b:
    if a%2==0:
      print('/2')
      a=a/2
    if a%2 !=0:
      print('-1')
      a=-1
```

Задача состоит в том, что есть два числа: одно начальное второе конечное и нужно довести одно число до второго.

Есть только две функции которые может использовать цикл /2 и -1.

Как это попроще реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

> Почему цикл остановился

Я бы пригляделся к этой строке: `a=-1`. Тут явная опечатка

> Как это попроще реализовать?

Немного отрефакторил:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
while a > b:
    if a % 2 == 0:
        print('/2')
        a /= 2
    else:
        print('-1')
        a -= 1
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Но ,в целом ,моя проблема не решилась.Если первое число 28 а второе число 4 то за такой схемой конечное число будет 3

Comment: Может у вас есть мысли на этот счёт ?

Comment: А тут какое конечное число?

Comment: Тут это где?Я не совсем понял

Comment: @Росомахич, `a=-1` сравните с `a -= 1`. В первом случае это присваивание `-1`, во втором вычитание `-1`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(input('От  '))
b = int(input('До  '))
while a > b:
    if a % 2 == 0 and a/2 >= b:
        print('/2', end=' : ')
        a /= 2
        print(a)
    else:
        print('-1', end=' : ')
        a -= 1
        print(a)
```

Comment: Спасибо чел, ты крут.